# Can a TypeScript interface constrain its implementing class's properties?

Tags: typescript, class, interface, signature, implements

I'd like to define a class, which can have any `string` property key, but with a specific corresponding value type. I tried the following:

```
interface MyValue {
  body: string;
  description: string;
}

interface MyInterface {
  [key: string]: MyValue;
}

class MyClass implements MyInterface {}
```

My hope was that the above would result in a `MyClass` where the following is valid:

```
class MyClass implements MyInterface {
  a = {
    body: "lorem ipsum";
    description: "some latin placeholder",
  };
}
```

... and the following is invalid:

```
class MyClass implements MyInterface {
  a = "lorem ipsum";
}
```

Instead I get an error:

```
Class 'MyClass' incorrectly implements interface 'MyInterface'.
  Index signature is missing in type 'MyClass'.
```

Is there a way to use a class and still achieve the desired behavior above?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I define a Typescript class which has an index signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977481/can-i-define-a-typescript-class-which-has-an-index-signature)

Comment: You can annotate your class with an index signature

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with an index signature. If your interface has an index siganture, your class will also need one.

You can constrain all key (properties and methods) of a class to a specific type using a mapped type:

```
type MyInterface<K extends PropertyKey> = {
  [P in K] : MyValue
}

class MyClassEmpty implements MyInterface<keyof MyClassEmpty> {}

class MyClassGood implements MyInterface<keyof MyClassGood> {
  a = {
    body: "lorem ipsum",
    description: "some latin placeholder",
  };
}

class MyClassBad implements MyInterface<keyof MyClassBad> {
  a = "lorem ipsum"; // error
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=1&pln=6&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8BqcA2BXFAbwChlkAjAewBN0AuZAZzClAHMBuU5aiRhVgAcwwSiAbNWITsQC+xYmHSCUGAJLho8JAB4A0sggAPSCGqNkABSiUVUJXojoAfMgC8yEmQDal5KGQ9AF1kBgxsfAg5BQQcOEYLDABhOISAUQBbYXR-LJwIDIhwRPQNSFhECB0AaydKGDR0FPjGTOzXQnliWJbG5oSAcUoaXMF8wuLGsq1KmrqG5NTGIZoO7jh3T24yKloGACIcSigC-0FGPAz9gBptnj4BYGFRcWR9xkpC5DiREGQxyoAC0oOF4UBu3FkXC6PQSfSWACE4NRRuMimAStMKrpauh6vCWkjqGsyBsPIdjqcnhcrhxkAB6emGKA2KDRIA)

Comment: It's not treating the fields as sealed. If you add more props to `a` of `MyGoodClass`, we see no error. @titian-cernicova-dragomir –– how do we prevent this?

Comment: @HarrySolovay That is a different question IMO, generally types are open in TS, If you were to declare the interface with the index signature, the properties could have more fields. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8BqcA2BXFAbwChlkAjAewBN0AuZAZzClAHMBuU5aiRhVgAcwwSiAbNWITsQC+xYqEixEKDAElw0eEmQkyAbQDWEekxbsAugwzZ8ELvOIIccRozToAwq-fJgALaCOBABEOAeGloquvrIxqYSFtLWnnYEXGRwyAC8etxkVLQMAEQ4lFCh-oKMeAElADQFPHwCwMKi4sgljJRhyK4iIMjBqgAWlDi8UI3N5HDUAApQlIKlJdyyjkA

Comment: if I were to try and assign extra fields to a variable typed as `MyValue`, I would get a TypeScript error. For that reason, I believe it to be part of the same question. I'd greatly appreciate this piece of the answer. & thank you for your tremendous help thus far.

Comment: it seems that this might be a limitation to the language. Unless the `MyValue` type is specified per-field, inheritance-related inference doesn't care; because of structural typing, an additional field has no impact––the type-checker perceives a subclass of `MyValue`, which is valid. It'd be nice if there was a way to work around this and achieve greater strictness in implementing classes.

Comment: @HarrySolovay There are ways to force 'exact types' on these fields, although they all have pitfalls, although I believe some approach could be use to ensure what you want. See this thread https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936#issuecomment-559603805

Comment: I read through the beginning and end of that thread... it doesn't seem like `implements` is able to communicate the field constraint (that extra fields within props are disallowed). Is this correct? If so, can you please add it to your answer above for others looking for this info? (and I'll of course add the check :)