# How to declare one type for all class methods in typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to force all methods return the same type.

Like this:

```
interface ITextGenerator {
  [key: string]: () => string
}

class TextGenerator implements ITextGenerator {
  genarator1 = () => "text1"

  genarator2 = () => "text2
}
```

---

Error in TextGenerator:

> Class 'TextGenerator' incorrectly implements interface 'ITextGenerator'.
> Index signature is missing in type 'TextGenerator'.

Comment: You can add the index signature to the class like so: https://tsplay.dev/mMyvZm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I define a Typescript class which has an index signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977481/can-i-define-a-typescript-class-which-has-an-index-signature)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following to make it work:

```
interface ITextGenerator {
  [key: string]:  () => string;
}

class TextGenerator implements ITextGenerator{

  [key: string]:  () => string; // This is important but i think kinda redundant

  test = () => '33'; // this is fine
  error = 33; // this is not okay
}
```

I actually don't know the reason why this is needed so if you find out let me know.

Comment: Hey, it breaks key of.

Try: `type AvailableTextGenerators = keyof TextGenerator`